# Python Efficiency - Better version than multiple if elif statements - use a for loop - chr ord conversions?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, chr, ord

I'm taking an intro to an online Python course and here's the problem description.

> Write a program which does the reverse of the example above: it should take a character as input and output the corresponding number (between 1 and 26). Your program should only accept capital letters. As error-checking, print invalid if the input is not a capital letter.

Can someone reply with a more efficient way of writing the following?

```
letter = input()
x = ord(letter)
if x >= ord('A') and x == 65:
   print(1)
elif x >= ord('A') and x == 66:
   print(2)
elif x >= ord('A') and x == 67:
   print(3)
elif x >= ord('A') and x == 68:
   print(4)
elif x >= ord('A') and x == 69:
   print(5)
elif x >= ord('A') and x == 70:
   print(6)
elif x >= ord('A') and x == 71:
   print(7)
elif x >= ord('A') and x == 72:
   print(8)


else:
   print("invalid")
```

I was thinking of some kind of for loop. I started several versions of for loops, but can't figure out how to handle the iterator and correspond it to the increasing asci value. Thanks! [This chr ord chart could help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrEAh.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any loops to solve this. Firstly, realize that you repeat the first test in each `elif`, so let's pull that right out to the top:

```
if x < ord('A')
```

Now, there are only a limited range of possible values for our `x`. In fact, the valid values for `x` also include `x < ord('A')` so we can remove that test:

```
if x < 65 or x > 72:
    print("invalid")
```

Ok, now we only have valid results left. There's actually a very simple formula for what you print: it ends up being `x - 64`. So that can go in the `else` part:

```
else:
    print(x - 64)
```

So the whole thing ends up being:

```
x = ord(letter)
if x < 65 or x > 72:
    print('invalid')
else:
    print(x - 64)
```

Note that the capital letters span more than this. However, the fix should be fairly simple.

Comment: You could simplify you `if` statements there.

Comment: @sberry Yeah, I realized that just after I posted it. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
letter = input()
x = ord(letter)
if x>64:
    print x-64
else:
    print "invalid"
```

more compact wit turnary operator

```
x = ord(input())
print (x-64 if x>64 else 'invalid')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without giving away the full solution: You could [1] Check first if `x` is not a capital letter (check out `string.uppercase`), and then [2] (Now that you know `x` is indeed a capital letter), return the `ord(x) - n` where `n` is the order at which the capital letters start (try `ord('A') - 1`).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
ord(letter)-64 if 65<=ord(letter)<=90 else 'Invalid'
```